# How to pass the values from multiple strings for insert into a sqlite table using a dbadapter?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

On click I want to insert values from 2 strings into a table using a `dbadapter` class. I am able to insert one string `inputparticulars` with column name `TX_PARTICULARS`. But I am unable to insert the 2nd string value into another column named as `TX_AMOUNT` of the same row.

```
public long insertTxData(String inputparticulars){         
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();    
    ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();    
    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_PARTICULARS,inputparticulars);    
    //contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_AMOUNT, inputamount);        
    contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_DATE, Calendar.DATE);     
    long id = db.insert(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, null, contentvalues );      
    return id;        
}     

public void  onTxClick(View v)     
{     
    String inputparticulars=particulars.getText().toString();         
    String inputamount=amount.getText().toString();         
    ContentValues contentvalues=new ContentValues();        
    vivzHelper.insertTxData(inputparticulars);
}
```

Comment: but you have `contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_AMOUNT, inputamount); ` commented out

Comment: if not commented i get error at 'inputamount'

Comment: because `inputamount` is not defined at the local scope of the `insertTxData`, it knows only about `inputparticulars` parameter

Comment: how to make insertamount also to be definedfor insertion into that row.

Comment: `public long insertTxData(String inputparticulars, String inputamount)`

Comment: I tried like that but get error at contentvalues.put..

Comment: contentvalues.put.. accepts only one string.

Comment: what error do you get? post updated code

Comment: I am trying like this: contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_PARTICULARS,inputparticulars);
            contentvalues.put(VivzHelper.TX_PARTICULARS,inputamount);